# Repair bootloader of a .DISK file

Tags: boot, mount, ubuntu-netbook

I have a .disk file which contains an exported web server. The web server was using a central bootloader system prior to it being exported.

I now have a disk file that won't boot and needs repairing. Can someone please advise how I repair this file? I found out how to mount the file onto /dev/loop0/ and be able to browse the filesystem, but now I do not know how to actually repair it.

I cannot attach this file to a VM as an additional hard-drive because the file type is not recognised.

I have the following resources available to me: 
- VMware Workstation
- Virtualbox 
- Various Windows/Linux VM's.

Answer (score 0):

Answer: 
1. Create new Ubuntu VM with a spare, second disk
2. Load into Ubuntu, go to disks and click Restore Image on the second disk
3. Once disk has restored, shutdown and boot into Live CD
4. Run Ubuntu, install boot-repair
5. Run boot-repair on second disk, choosing this location for GRUB to be placed - fix any errors that appear (these are prompts and copy+paste)
6. Shutdown machine, boot into BIOS, select second disk as boot priority #1
7. It should boot into the said disk without issues. 
8. The disk is now bootable, and in vmdk format (I used VMware), so a new VM can be created using the existing disk.